# Is it possible to change the CNI plugin to Calico in GKE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, calico

It seems like EKS (AWS) has the support for some CNIs [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/managed-public-cloud/eks) but we couldn't find any similar doc for GKE (GCP)

is it possible to change the CNI plugins of GKE clusters? Can I change the CNI of our GKE v1.18.x cluster to Calico with IP-in-IP encapsulation?

Answer (score 1):

GKE has built-in support for Calico via network policy enforcement in clusters which are not using Dataplane V2.

You can enable network policy enforcement on an existing cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --update-addons=NetworkPolicy=ENABLED
```

and then enable it for existing nodepools (which will be recreated):

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --enable-network-policy
```

This actually installs Calico so you should have access to the entire Calico API.

Comment: Thanks! for your answer. We wanted to switch to Calico as the CNI plugin for our cluster instead of just enabling the N/W policies. so is it possible?

Comment: If you enable the N/W policy add-on, it installs Calico under the covers so you should also be able to use other Calico features besides N/W policy.

Comment: Thanks Gari for the reply. is there any chance we can choose a specific version of the Calico CNI with IP-in-IP encapsulation?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in the feedback from Gari you can follow the next steps in order to enabled the network policy enforcement.

[Enabling network policy enforcement](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy#enabling_network_policy_enforcement)

Network policy enforcement is built into GKE Dataplane V2. You do not need to enable network policy enforcement in clusters that use GKE Dataplane V2.

When you enable network policy enforcement in a GKE cluster that doesn't use GKE Dataplane V2, GKE manages and enforces network policies within that cluster.

**Caution:**

**By default, enabling network policy enforcement for your cluster also enables enforcement for the cluster's nodes.**

You can enable network policy enforcement in GKE by using the gcloud tool, the Google Cloud Console, or the GKE API.

To enable network policy enforcement when creating a new cluster, run the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME --enable-network-policy
```

Replace CLUSTER_NAME with the name of the new cluster.

To enable network policy enforcement for an existing cluster, perform the following tasks:

1. Run the following command to enable the add-on:

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --update-addons=NetworkPolicy=ENABLED
```

Replace CLUSTER_NAME with the name of the cluster.

2. Run the following command to enable network policy enforcement on your cluster, which in turn recreates your cluster's node pools with network policy enforcement enabled:

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --enable-network-policy
```

Comment: Thanks @Arden for the reply. is there any chance we can choose a specific version of the Calico with IP-in-IP encapsulation?

Comment: Hello Oli, is not possible